# Append element does not show after running function twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a function I am working on, basically if I click the trigger once the hiddend is being displayed, but after clicking the trigger twice the element to display is gone all gone. I will appreciate any help with this. I am including a jsFiddle at http://www.jsfiddle.net/AUhPc/

```
$(function() {
/* Creating the overlay content elements needed */
    var overlay = $('<div class="overlay"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var overlay_content = $('<div class="overlay-content"></div>').appendTo(overlay);
    var overlay_content_inner = $('<div class="overlay-content-inner"></div>').appendTo(overlay_content);
    var btn_remove = $('<i class="i-remove">Close</i>').appendTo(overlay_content);
    //$('.user-comment-item').css({"position":"relative"})

    $('.my-list li .button').on("click", function() {
        var button = $(this);
//      overlay_content_inner.empty();
        overlay.fadeIn(300,function(){
            button.find('.user-comment-list').css({"display":"block"}).appendTo(overlay_content_inner);
        });
    });
    btn_remove.click(function(){
        overlay.fadeOut(300,function(){});
    });
});
```

Comment: As a side-note, instead of `$('.my-list li .button').on('click',`, I recommend `$('.my-list').on('click', '.button',`.

Comment: Also, instead of `.css({"display":"block"})`, why not just `.show()`?

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler:

```
$("my-list li.button").off("click");
```

To remove the click handler. You can also use:

```
$("my-list li.button").one("click", callback);
```

If you only want the click callback to happen once.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because of this line

```
overlay_content_inner.empty();
```

You are clearing the contents from the overlay_content_inner div because of which the next time you click the button the data is not shown..

Try removing that line and then try.. It should not be a problem..

Comment: After deleting the .empty(); line, every time i click thre trigger, my container box is appending all the childs elements from the <li>, you can see this happening here. http://jsfiddle.net/AUhPc/1/